# Sorting dictionary - Exception Value: unhashable type: 'set'

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I have an `OrderedDict` groups:

```
{2:set([0,0,0]),4:set([0,0]),6:set([0,0,0,0])}
```

which values are sets. I'm trying to order this dictionary by values lengths.

```
OrderedDict(sorted(groups.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(groups[x]), reverse=True))
```

This returns:

> Exception Value:  unhashable type: 'set'

Do you know how to make this work or a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket after the first set.

Comment: It was a typo but it's not the problem.